# Azure Appregistration to manage ExchangeOnline Missing Parameters in Remove-DistributionGroupMember -BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Hi I have small problem with Exchange Online unattended scripts
I connect to exchange online as appregistration with Exchange.ManageasApp application permissions.
I have created Exchange Service Principal and assigned it to Organization Management Admin Role (Role Group) to enable role Security Group Creation and Membership.

I can't execute Remove-DistributionGroupMember -BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck
with error :
Remove-DistributionGroupMember : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck'

Any ideas what more I need to do to make it work?

Triad adding Organization Managment Role Group to service princpal.

Answer (score 0):

I had to recreate service principal and assigne managment role once again.
Just remember to add info from Enterprise apps not app registration.